# Object in Constructor Parameters: Create New Instance, or Assign Pointer?

Tags: java, pointers, object, arguments

If a class contains an object as an instance variable, and one of the constructors includes an object of the same type as a parameter, is it best practice to assign the argument to the instance variable, or to create a new object from the argument, and assign THE NEW OBJECT to the instance variable.

Here's an example from an exercise I'm working through:

```
public class MyCircle {

  private MyPoint center; //contains variables int x and int y
  private int radius;

  //Non-controversial Constructor:
  public MyCircle(int x, int y, int radius ) {
    //creates new center using a valid MyPoint constructor
    this.center = new MyPoint(x, y);
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  //OPTION A
  public MyCircle( MyPoint center, int radius ) {
    this.center = center;
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  //OPTION B
  public MyCircle( MyPoint center, int radius ){
    this.center = new MyPoint( center.getX(), center.getY() );
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}
```

Initially, I typed option A, but I thought that this could create buggy behavior if `this.center` referenced an existing object that could be modified indirectly unintentionally.  The alternative way of thinking about it, I guess, is that this creates an avenue for creating multiple objects that share a center, and moving a single center would intentionally move all circles that share that center.

Comment: There's no real best practice here because you might want the calling code to be able to modify the center. Or you don't. You could also make sure that a ``MyPoint`` is immutable so that the values for ``x`` and ``y`` cannot be changed, that would also eliminate the need for copying the ``MyPoint`` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java has no pointers  (at least not for developers) that option will be discarded and  is not the way to go..
Now this:

```
public MyCircle( MyPoint center, int radius ) {
    this.center = center;
    this.radius = radius;   }
```

Is in my opinion better, you can just assign the center and don't need to make a risky copy of the class MyPoint... And I say risky because if you want to do that you should at least check the non-null condition of that parameter....

You can for sure think... what if center is null in option A, you are right, that can happen, then you can take care of it by either throwing an illegalparameterexception, or just assigning that object to a default value. ..

But as I said before is my opinion..

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize "pointer" was such a specific term.  The question should really be, "...create a new object or assign a reference to an existing object"?  I also appreciate the warning that MyPoint, or some similar object might be null.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your program. If you want the circle to have a reference to the `MyPoint` object, then you must pass it. Otherwise, why not pass in the actually `x` and `y` values themselves.

For example, option B can be written as:

```
public MyCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
   // rest 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

both options are fine, but as you told, an object may change in the time, the option A is ok when you want to modify the center in more than one object at the same time, for example in an List of Circles, but if you want to have unique and independient center points, option B is correct. So you why don't you have both constructors and use one or another depending many cases in your app, use whatever you want you consider better, keep both, it is my advice.

Hope it helps to you.